# android screen background is black for "samsung duos only" when not defined any color as background

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, background, screen

I have lot of screens on my diiferent apps which works perfectly for any device(I tried on 15-20 devices) except only for Samsung DUOS where the background color of a layout looks black if I don't define any `android:background="` for that layout.

Does any one other have this issue?
The device is GT-S7262 with 4.1.2

And it happens with almost all screens of my 3-4 applications.

Exactly saying, when i define a layout without mentioning any background color, then every device, the background takes the background color of parent layout, but only for that device it looks black.

Comment: i had the same problem on devices with android 4.1, i had to set the color transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the background color as transparent.

Comment: added   <solid android:color="@color/transparent" > </solid> in background drawable, and it worked.

Comment: <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>